# PowerApps merge related tables

Tags: relational-database, powerapps

I'm new to PowerApps and am exploring relational databases before starting a project in PowerApps (involving relational databases). I'm trying to do a simple join of two entities (drink and human), where the drink has a BuyerID field which relates to a "human"'s Primary ID.
So I tried
`ForAll(Filter(drink, (name = "Americano") And (drink.BuyerID = human.PrimaryId) ), Collect(AmericanoDrinkers, {FirstName: human.firstName, LastName: human.lastName}))`
to get a collection of humans who brought an Americano, but I get an `Invalid argument type` error with `drink.BuyerID = human.PrimaryId`. 
Any ideas? I've tried changing `=` to `in` and stuff like `drink.BuyerID` to `drink[@BuyerID]`. Note that the drink.BuyerID datatype is "Lookup" and human.PrimaryId is integer, so could I be getting this error because of the different types? Also I'm certain there's nothing wrong with the data because when editting the drink entity in excel, the powerapps add-on shows the related humans when a BuyerID is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just the setup, I just created a new field (BuyerID2) in the drinks entity and set it as a number value rather than a lookup like BuyerID was, and all 3 (my initial one, and the two Meneghino provided) solutions worked fine (although I had to change `drink.BuyerID = human.PrimaryId` to `BuyerID2 in human.PrimaryId`).

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do in theory is this:

```
ClearCollect(AmericanoDrinkers,
    Filter(human,
        PrimaryId in Filter(drink, name="Americano").BuyerID
            )
        )
    )
```

In practice, depending on what your data source is for drink and/or human you may run into delegation issues.
I do not recommend the use of ForAll if you can avoid it, since you risk data source calls for every row, whereas a formula like the one I suggest will be processed in parallel (delegation permitting).

If the performance of the above is not satisfactory, you could also try this two-step approach:

```
ClearCollect(FilteredIds, GroupBy(Filter(drink, name="Americano"), "BuyerID", "AllRows"));
ClearCollect(AmericanoDrinkers, Filter(human, PrimaryId in FilteredIds.BuyerID))
```

Comment: Good thinking, but I get "Cannot automatically convert this Text value to a record" error for `PrimaryId`, and `human.PrimaryId` gets "Cannot use table values in this context". Also the "in" function is not delegable, but that's another story.

Comment: I have just tested and my original one-step approach should work, are you sure you include the .BuyerID? This turns the table into a list of values so PrimaryId should be text and not a record.  In any case I have added a two-step approach so you can even inspect the contents of FilteredIds to check if all is as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Gallery inside a gallery....
I have used Gallery inside a gallery many times, it is kinda confusing to work with it, but seems very logical and worked fine for me.